Irrepeatability in computeCartesianPath() function
I am using Noetic with the open-manipulator x arm and controlling it using move group. I am able to successfully execute my cartesian path sometimes, and others, it will not go past the first 10%, without changing a single thing except maybe the temperature in the room.
I have also noticed that changing the input parameters of the computecartesianpath function (step and jump), will maybe? impact my repeatability, but really there is no way to be sure since I can not seem to observe any pattern.
Do any of you kind fellows have any ideas as to why this would be happening or how to fix?
###### Setup ########
moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
rospy.init_node('move_group_python_execute_trajectory', anonymous=True)

robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()
scene = moveit_commander.PlanningSceneInterface()
arm_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("arm")
gripper_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("gripper")
display_trajectory_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/move_group/display_planned_path', moveit_msgs.msg.DisplayTrajectory, queue_size=1)

#Had probelms with planner failing, Using this planner now. I believe default is OMPL
#arm_group.set_planner_id("STOMP")
#gripper_group.set_planner_id("RRTConnectkConfigDefault")
#Increased available planning time from 5 to 20 seconds
arm_group.set_planning_time(20);
gripper_group.set_planning_time(20);

#Points in example
arm_group.remember_joint_values(names1, values1)
arm_group.remember_joint_values(names2, values2)

gripper_group_variable_values = gripper_group.get_current_joint_values()

###### Main ########

#Pose goal - not as efficient as cartesian path.
'''pose_goal = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
pose_goal.orientation.w  = 1
pose_goal.position.x = 0
pose_goal.position.y = 0
pose_goal.position.z = 0

arm_group.set_pose_target(pose_goal)
plan = arm_group.go(wait = True)
variable = arm_group.get_current_pose()
print (variable.pose)'''

#Cartesian Path

move_home()
open_gripper()

#Rotate EEF up 90 deg - can either use the joint, or trying to manipulate the orientation...

#joint_goal = arm_group.get_current_joint_values()
#joint_goal[3] -= 0.8
#arm_group.go(joint_goal, wait = True)

##trying....
#rot = Rotation.from_euler('xyz',[0,-90,0],degrees = True)
#quat = rot.as_quat()
#pose_goal = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
#pose_goal.orientation.y = np.cos(45)
#pose_goal.orientation.w  = np.sin(45)
#pose_goal.orientation.x = 0
#pose_goal.orientation.z = 0

#arm_group.set_pose_target(pose_goal)
#arm_group.go(wait = True)

#Cock back and execute

waypoints = []
arm_group.clear_pose_targets()
homepose = arm_group.get_current_pose().pose
wpose = arm_group.get_current_pose().pose
for i in range(1):
    wpose.position.x -= 0.03
    wpose.position.z += 0.04
    waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))

#Throw and execute.

for i in range(3):
    wpose.position.x += 0.04
    #wpose.position.z -= 0.02
    waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))
    
waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(homepose))
#Execute path
#print(waypoints)
plan, fraction = arm_group.compute_cartesian_path(waypoints, 0.012, 0)
arm_group.execute(plan, wait = True)

print('frac', fraction)

#move_home()
close_gripper()

moveit_commander.roscpp_shutdown()


Please use backticks (\``) and not single quotes (') for code fencing to code format, like this (``` ... ````)

I don't think your arm model has 6 degrees of freedom, which means you can unintentionally specify a trajectory that the eef is unable to follow. Remember by default you are specifying a pose (both eef-position and eef-orientation.)
When first working with an arm, one thing that can help is to relax how accurate the IK solutions need to be, especially with eef-orientation. For moveit_commander, I suggest you look at the methods set_goal_position_tolerance() and set_goal_orientation_tolerance().
